# Refresh Visual webpart through Javascript in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, refresh, visual-web-developer-2010

I have added visual webpart in home page. Can any one provide me java script to refresh this Webpart for every 2 minutes.

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Sandy

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this without additional JavaScript. What if you build the timing into your web part (using a timer)? You can then expose a Web part property that can allow the end user adjust the refresh interval. If you don't need to adjust the refresh interval, then you don't need to expose the property.Hope this helps.

SAMPLE
follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sp2010devtrainingcourse_sharepointdevelopmentwithvisualstudio2010lab_topic6.aspx) to know how to use ajax in Visual Web Parts. then do the following

### ASCX MARKUP

```
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="177px" Width="269px"></asp:ListBox>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" 
            onprerender="Timer1_PreRender" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </div>
```

### ASCX CODE BEHIND

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace vwpTestAjaxRefresh.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz");
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Hello World at " + currenttime);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please give me a hello world example for using the timer in this scenario?

Comment: @sandy_9866141457 see the update to my initial answer above. Added Sample Code.

Comment: Once again thanks for your reply.If you see my code above which i have posted it is same as you have done. I am using java script to show the alert banner on the page. There is no relation ship for the timer. In the above code Label DateStampLabel is getting refreshed but not the other label  lblScripter. Not sure why this is happening any help on this much appreciated.

Comment: You are doing too many things at the same time. Leave only the basic codes. don't do visible=true/false. do text="Whatever"/"". Remove all JavaScripts. Make sure your timer_tick code is working before doing other fancy stuff. That way you'll know what's wrong.

Comment: I tried it and my code is working fine . But my label i.e lblScripter is not geeting refreshed???

Comment: After doing lot of debugging i found that the java script is not calling on Timer1_Tick. Can any one tell me how to call the java script on the same.

Comment: put this in the load.                    lblScripter.Attributes.Add("onClick", "showbox1()");//showbox1() is a javascript function and onClick is the client event to trigger the script

Comment: Sorry id idnt get your answer. Can you please elaborate more on the same

Comment: If you wish to trigger javascript on managed Objects (C#) then you need to attach the javascript function to the client side event that should trigger using the code above. So, if you know any client side event that fires on any of your managed objects/controls at the point where you want your javascript to execute, use the Attributes.Add() of that object to attach the javascript function to the client-side event. Sorry if I confused you. It's a mouth full.